# Python Selenium not finding element

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, element

I am trying to find the other sellers of an product by the class name but no matter what it will not locate it. I have checked that is not in an iframe. Any help?

Python Code

```
 def similarproducts(self):
        print("Finding other sellers")
        try:
            self.othersellers = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
                EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'a-box mbc-offer-row pa_mbc_on_amazon_offer')))

        except TimeoutException:
            print("Found no sellers")
```

Link to page:
[https://www.amazon.com/Bentgo-Kids-Childrens-Lunch-Box/dp/B00PKNO7LK/ref=sr_1_4?dchild=1&keywords=Bentgo%2BKids%2BPrints%2B(Camouflage)%2B-%2BLeak-Proof%2C%2B5-Compartment%2BBento-Style%2BKids%2BLunch%2BBox%2B%E2%80%93%2BIdeal%2BPortion%2BSizes%2Bfor%2BAges%2B3%2Bto%2B7%2B%E2%80%93%2BBPA-Free%2Band%2BFood-Safe%2BMaterials&qid=1624574710&s=home-garden&sr=1-4&th=1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00PKNO7LK)

Comment: What are you trying to do here? To get the other sellers name? To add to the  shopping cart from alternative seller?

Comment: @Prophet I am trying to find the price of the product, then if the product is cheaper or the same price as the original product, then it buys it.

Answer (score 0):

The alternative seller price can be found by:

```
alternative_price = driver.find.element_by_css_selector("#mbc-price-1").text
```

Adding the product to the shopping cart can be done with:

```
driver.find.element_by_css_selector("#mbc-buybutton-addtocart-1 .a-button-input")
```

**UPD**
In case several alternative sellers available you can open the alternative sellers view by clicking this:

```
driver.find.element_by_css_selector("div.olp-text-box").click()
```

Now you can get all the prices:

```
price_els = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@id,'aod-price-')]")
prices = []
for price in price_els:
    prices.append(price.text)
```

To add a product to cart you can use:

```
driver.find_elements_by_xpath('(//input[@name="submit.addToCart"])[x]').click()
```

where `x` is the index according to the price elements above.
To open the alternative sellers menu you can click this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.olp-text-box').click()
```

To close alternative sellers view click this:

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('#aod-close i.a-icon-close').click()
```

Comment: How about finding other sellers? This would work if there's always only one.

Comment: I saw no such pages, tried several. Can you give me a link or two with multiple "other sellers"?

Comment: the link I gave has multiple sellers. Under adding to list and what not

Answer (score 0):

See if this works:-

```
otherSellers = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[text()='Other Sellers on Amazon']//following::div[@class='a-box mbc-offer-row pa_mbc_on_amazon_offer']//following::span[contains(@id,'mbc-price')]")
for e in otherSellers:
    print(e.text)
```